# What's the most efficient way to perform an action based on matching form input values using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Let's say I have three related text input fields:

```
<input name="x1" class="xField" value="" /><div class="note" style="display:none;">Match</div>
<input name="x2" class="xField" value="" /><div class="note" style="display:none;">Match</div>
<input name="x3" class="xField" value="" /><div class="note" style="display:none;">Match</div>
```

Now, when the value of any of these changes, and it matches the value of *another* one of the related fields, I want to "un-hide" the `.note` div next to each input with matching value.

So, this is what I have so far:

```
$(function() {
    $(".xField").change(updateCommentsDisplay);

    function updateCommentsDisplay() {
        var $aVisibleNotes = [];

        $(".xField").each(function() {
            // If more than one field with the same value, add the next note div to an array
            if ($(".xField[value="+$(this).val()).length > 1)
                $aVisibleNotes.push($(this).next(".note");
        });

        $.each($aVisibleNotes, function(){
            $(this).show();
        });
    }
});
```

This just doesn't feel efficient. I feel like I should be able to do this without loops. Any suggestions?

Comment: `$aVisibleNotes.push($(this).next(".note");` - are you missing a parethesis?

Answer (score 1):

To do it without loops, simply use selectors.  Also specify `not(this)` if you don't want the input to show the note following it.

```
$(".xField").keyup(function(){
    var val=$(this).val();       
    $('.xField[value='+val+']').not(this).next(":hidden").show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine selectors to get the result....xField, same value, different input = show the next note.

```
$('.xField').change(function() {
    var x = $(this);
    $('.xField[value="' + x.val() + '"]')
            .not(this).next('.note').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping through each input just use a selector to find the inputs whose value matches:

```
$(function() {
    $(".xField").change(function(){
        var field_val = $(this).val();
        $(".xField[value='" + field_val + "']").show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, you should save the results of $(".xField');

So:

```
$(function() {
    var xFields = $('.xField');
    xFields.change(updateCommentsDisplay);

    function updateCommentsDisplay() {
        var $aVisibleNotes = [];

        xFields.each(function() {
            // If more than one field with the same value, add the next note div to an array
            if(xFields.find('[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').size() > 1)
                $aVisibleNotes.push($(this).next(".note");
        });

        $.each($aVisibleNotes, function(){
            $(this).show();
        });
    }
});
```

It also might be faster to use an actual value comparison instead of the Sizzle engine to find matches. You'd want to test it on jsperf, but I have a hunch.

Comment: I agree with cache of the array of elements

Answer (score 0):

turn them on and off if matches or no matches:

```
$(".xField").change(function() {
        updateCommentsDisplay();
});

function updateCommentsDisplay() {
    $(".xField").each(function() {
        if ($(".xField[value=" + $(this).val() + "]").length > 1) {
            $(this).next(".note").show();
        }
        else {
            $(this).next(".note").hide();
        };
    });
};
```

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/UrBEk/

Comment: IF you DO need the array for some reason you can simply select the elements that are NOT hidden at any point. `$('.note').not(':hidden')`

Comment: Note: IF you only want to show if it EVER matched something you can get rid of the `else` - and it will still show.